# SwiftUI NavigationLink Keyboard

Tags: swiftui

В приложении хочу реализовать поиск и сокрытие клавиатуры после перехода по NavigationLink.
Сейчас клавиатура скрывается после прокрутки списка, но при переходе по NavigationLink и возвращению к ContentView, клавиатура остается активной.

Прошу подсказать каким образом это можно реализовать.

```
struct ContentView: View {
       let array = ["John","Lena","Steve","Chris","Catalina"]

            @State private var searchText = ""

            var body: some View {


                NavigationView{
                  List{
                      TextField("Type your search",text: $searchText)
                          .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                      ForEach(array.filter{$0.hasPrefix(searchText) || searchText == ""}, id:\.self){names in
                        NavigationLink(destination:keyboardDissmis(text: names)){
                              Text(names)
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  .navigationBarTitle(Text("Search"))
              }
                .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged{_ in UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to:nil, from:nil, for:nil)})

        }
    }

    func keyboardDissmis(text:String)->Text{
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to:nil, from:nil, for:nil)

        return Text(text)
    }


    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так

```
//...
ForEach(array.filter{$0.hasPrefix(searchText) || searchText == ""}, id:\.self){names in
                    NavigationLink(destination:Text(names)){
                        Text(names).onAppear {
                            UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
                        }
                    }
                }
//...

extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to:nil, from:nil, for:nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Данная реализация в методе при появлении представления работает. Единственное смущает вывод в консоле:  2019-12-19 19:46:12.673021+0300 [14995:1005092] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x7fdac9cebe90, UIInputSetContainerView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.

Comment: @Alse причина данного предупреждения мне до конца непонятна, а данном случае она связана с показом клавиатуры, в целом его можно игнорировать или попытаться починить как указано здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56898912/getting-a-snapshotting-error-when-leaving-app-after-keyboard-was-shown-requires или здесь https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63306. Кстати это предупреждение возникает и при сворачивании приложения с открытой клавиатурой. К нашему вопросу это не относится, если мой ответ вас устроил, поставьте галку